# What prevents infinite loops among interconnected Winforms controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

On a Form I have two controls, A and B.  Each one sends an event when its value changes. The Form handles A's ValueChanged event by setting B to some value, and B's ValueChanged by setting A's value.

Do I need to do anything special to prevent an infinite loop, where the user changes A, sending a ValueChanged event which causes B to update, which now sends  it ValueChanged event, causing A to update...

I know some GUI toolkits, such as Qt, have logic built into the infrastructure to prevent loops like that. (See the "Enter Your Age" example in Ch. 1 of the Blanchette & Summerfield book on Qt4.) Some older toolkits required the programmer to define and manage a flag to detect recursion.   For WinForms, I haven't read a definitive statement anywhere on this.

For a concrete example, suppose A and B are NumericUpDown controls to show temperature in Fahrenheit and Celsius.  When the user changes one, the other updates to show the corresponding temperature in the other system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way in which I've managed to prevent this problem when implementing custom controls, is by raising events only when the value actually does get changed, like this.

```
public string Text
{
    get { return _text; }
    set
    {
        if (_text != value)
        {
            _text = value;
            OnTextChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

One could argue that not checking whether the value is actually different before firing the event is bad code.

I don't recall ever experiencing these issues with Windows Forms controls, so the ones I've been using must be doing this check correctly.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the loop usually ends because the values stop actually changing.  Your example falls into this case.  Consider the following scenario:

- User changes the Fahrenheit to 32
- Events update the Celsius to 0
- Events set the Fahrenheit to 32
- Nothing further happens because Fahrenheit did not change

This is usually implemented in the properties by putting a check at the top of the setter to not raise the changed event when the new value is the same as the current value.

Comment: _This is usually implemented in the properties by putting a check at the top of the setter to not raise the changed event when the new value is the same as the current value._ implemented by whom?

Comment: In the case of Windows Forms Controls, it is the control that has this implemented within. Unless the value is changed the ValueChanged event is not fired for NumericUpDown.

Answer (score 1):

The events will not loop in the NumericUpDown example that you have provided. The **ValueChanged event of the NumericUpDown will only get fired when the value changes** i.e. If the value of a NumericUpDown is 5 and in code you again set it to 5, no event will be fired. This behavior of the event stops it from looping when you have two NumericUpDown controls.

Now suppose you have two NumericUpDown controls A & B.

1. A was changed by the user, it fires an event
2. On the event fired by A, you calculate and set the value of B. B detects a value change and fires an event
3. On the event fired by B, you calculate and set the value of A. However this value would be the same as the original value and Windows will **not** fire an event of ValueChanged.

So in the case of *Windows Form Controls, the Framework manages it for you,* if you want to achieve this for your own classes you follow a similar principle. On the setter of a value, check if the new value is different from the old value. Only if it differs fire an event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should detach B event before set B in A event. So B event never fire when you set B in A event. you should same thing for B event. You can break loop.

Sorry for my English. I hope it help you.

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any standard. As a user, you should handle controls that raise useless events, and controls that do not. Even for .NET's own controls, documentation is lacking on this aspect so you're left just trying it.

Using a flag to detect recursion is possible, but nicer IMO is to change `control.Value = newvalue;` to `if (control.Value != newvalue) control.Value = newvalue;`.

That said, if you write your own controls, please do not raise useless events, and please clearly document that fact.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I have built a simple test with the code below.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random r = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This triggers the infinite loop between the two controls
        numericUpDown1.Value = 10;
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int cur = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
        int r1 = r.Next(1, 100);
        while (r1 == cur)
            r1 = r.Next(1, 100);

        Console.WriteLine("Random in NUM1=" + r1);
        numericUpDown2.Value = r1;
    }

    private void numericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int cur = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        int r1 = r.Next(1, 100);
        while (r1 == cur)
            r1 = r.Next(1, 100);

        Console.WriteLine("Random in NUM2=" + r1);
        numericUpDown1.Value = r1;
    }
}
```

The form has only two NumericUpDown initialized with values 1 and 2.

As you could test in Visual Studio 2013 there is nothing to prevent an infinite recursion in the case in which you really manage to generate different numbers at every ValueChanged event.

To prevent the infinite loop you could use the usual technique. Declare a global form variable

```
 bool changing = false;
```

Inside both events add this code

```
try
{   
     if (changing) return;
     changing = true;
     .... event code ....
}
finally
{
     changing = false;
}
```